# Does it improve my credit if I pay my credit card bill off several times a month as I use it?

Tags: united-states, taxes, credit-card, loans, banking

I have a secured credit card of $200, if I used 30% (about $60) in the first time and pay my credit card balance in full after one week, then spend another $60 and pay it after a week, and continue in this way for using $60 and paying it for 4 times in one month is better to build a credit, or if I spend $60 and wait for due date and pay it before 30 days????

Comment: It does not matter. All that matters is that you pay it on time in regards to building credit

Comment: Additionally, credit score has no memory when it comes to balances. A loss in point due to high utilization one month is wiped away when you pay it off the next month. Be responsible with your debts and your credit profile will benefit

Answer (score 2):

Paying your outstanding balance multiple times during the billing cycle will not impact your credit score. There is no benefit to doing this from a payment history perspective. The credit company looks at the balance on the statement they send and whether that payment is late or not.

One benefit you may find to your credit score by paying more often is that it will keep your credit utilization percentage lower because you will be reducing your balance more often.  Unless you run your available credit up close to the limit regularly during the billing cycle so you are showing near 100% utilization, the benefit you get from this may not be worth the extra effort.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, only paying the bill that you are assigned for each period will build credit. That is to say, if you spend $200 in one month, and they ask for a payment of $25, only making sure you have paid that amount will have any direct impact on your credit.

Buying and paying off the card immediately is a good practice, and will keep you from building any debt, but it won't increase your credit score by simply repeating the process over and over during a single billing period.

Answer (score 1):

Always be aware of your credit utilization rate, which is not reported at the same time as your statement is generated.  Several of my cards seem to update utilization at least once a week, according to the credit monitoring services I use.  Carrying a high utilization rate (especially more than 30% of your limit) is not a positive thing for your short-term credit.
Keep in mind also that your credit card issuer will report your highest balance too, so that has something of an impact as well.  In other words, if you were to use $150 of your $200 limit, the card issuer will report to the bureaus that at one point you were using 75% of your available credit.

Paying your bill more than once a month does nothing to help your credit, because the card issuers will only show one payment on your account when they report.  It *does* help you keep your balance lower, which improves the utilization rate and leaves you room on the card in case of unexpected/emergency needs.

If your secured card is like most then you can increase your limit by adding to the savings account the card is tied to.  It would be well worth it to you to send maybe $20 a week or so to raise your limit so that a $60 purchase has much less effect on your utilization rate.
While having a secured card *does* help build your credit somewhat if you make your payments on time, having a low limit is a bit of a negative, so you want to see if you can get it increased.  Some banks, after 6 months of on-time payments, will be willing to talk to you about raising your limit without it being secured, while others will make you wait a year.  If you want to do it any sooner, you'll have to send in money to your savings account.

I hope this helps.

Good luck!